# whenever i run the app on emulator it says unfortunately the app has stopped working and the log reads the below lines

Tags: android

The MainActivity file

```
package com.example.intel.dualboot;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StatusAsyncTask.StatusAsyncTaskListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, MainActivityListener {
    private static final String TAG = "db::MainActivity";

    /* public static final int ACT_INSTALL_ROM        = 1;
    public static final int ACT_CHANGE_PAGE        = 2;
    public static final int ACT_SELECT_ICON        = 3;
    public static final int ACT_UNINSTALL_ROM      = 4;

    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST = "show_rom_list";*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 20) {
            showDeprecatedLAlert();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // This activity is using different background color, which would cause overdraw
        // of the whole area, so disable the default background
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        Utils.installHttpCache(this);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        m_srLayout = (InSwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
        m_srLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        m_curFragment = -1;

        m_fragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_fragment_titles);
        m_drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        m_drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        String[] fragmentClsNames = new String[MainFragment.MAIN_FRAG_CNT];
        for(int i = 0; i < fragmentClsNames.length; ++i)
            fragmentClsNames[i] = MainFragment.getFragmentClass(i).getName();

        m_fragments = new MainFragment[MainFragment.MAIN_FRAG_CNT];
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i) {
            m_fragments[i] = (MainFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentClsNames[i]);
            if(m_fragments[i] == null) {
                m_fragments[i] = MainFragment.newFragment(i);
                t.add(R.id.content_frame, m_fragments[i], fragmentClsNames[i]);
            }
            t.hide(m_fragments[i]);
        }
        t.commit();

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        m_drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list, m_fragmentTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        m_drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        m_drawerTitle = getText(R.string.app_name);
        m_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, m_drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(m_title);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(m_drawerTitle);
            }
        };
        m_drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(m_drawerToggle);

        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(bar != null) {
            bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        /*  if (getIntent().hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST) &&
                getIntent().getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST, false)) {
            getIntent().removeExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST);
            selectItem(1);
        } else if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            selectItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("curFragment", 0));
        } else {
            selectItem(0);
        }*/
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
        super.onNewIntent(i);
        if (i.hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST) &&
                i.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_ROM_LIST, false)) {
            selectItem(1);
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Utils.flushHttpCache();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curFragment", m_curFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        m_refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        if(!StatusAsyncTask.instance().isComplete())
            m_refreshItem.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        if(position < 0 || position >= m_fragments.length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid fragment index " + position);
            return;
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if(m_curFragment != -1)
            t.hide(m_fragments[m_curFragment]);
        t.show(m_fragments[position]);
        t.commit();

        m_curFragment = position;

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        m_drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(m_fragmentTitles[position]);
        m_drawerLayout.closeDrawer(m_drawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        m_title = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(m_title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(m_drawerToggle != null)
            m_drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(m_drawerToggle != null)
            m_drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem it) {
        if (m_drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(it))
            return true;

        switch(it.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                refresh(false);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_reboot:
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                b.setTitle("Reboot")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .setItems(R.array.reboot_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                switch (i) {
                                    case 0: Utils.reboot(""); break;
                                    case 1: Utils.reboot("recovery"); break;
                                    case 2: Utils.reboot("bootloader"); break;
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .create().show();
                return true;
            }

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void startRefresh(boolean notifyRefreshLayout) {
        if(notifyRefreshLayout)
            m_srLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        if(m_refreshItem != null)
            m_refreshItem.setEnabled(false);

        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i)
            m_fragments[i].startRefresh();

        StatusAsyncTask.instance().setListener(this);
        StatusAsyncTask.instance().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void refresh(boolean b) {
        refresh(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRefreshComplete() {
        m_srLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        if(m_refreshItem != null)
            m_refreshItem.setEnabled(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i)
            m_fragments[i].setRefreshComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentViewCreated() {
        if(++m_fragmentViewsCreated == m_fragments.length) {
            // postDelayed because SwipeRefresher view ignores
            // setRefreshing call otherwise
            m_srLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    if(i == null || !i.getBooleanExtra("force_refresh", false)) {
                        startRefresh(true);
                    } else {
                        i.removeExtra("force_refresh");
                        refresh(false);
                    }
                }
            }, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentViewDestroyed() {
        --m_fragmentViewsCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public void addScrollUpListener(InSwipeRefreshLayout.ScrollUpListener l) {
        m_srLayout.addScrollUpListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusTaskFinished(StatusAsyncTask.Result res) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_fragments.length; ++i)
            m_fragments[i].onStatusTaskFinished(res);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refresh(false);
    }

    @TargetApi(20)
    private void showDeprecatedLAlert() {
        SpannableString msg = new SpannableString("Android Developer preview has bugs");
        Linkify.addLinks(msg, Linkify.ALL);

        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setTitle("Unsupported Android version")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setNegativeButton("Exit Application", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog d = b.create();
        d.show();

        TextView msgView = (TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        msgView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

    private DrawerLayout m_drawerLayout;
    private ListView m_drawerList;
    private String[] m_fragmentTitles;
    private MainFragment[] m_fragments;
    private int m_curFragment;
    private CharSequence m_title;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle m_drawerToggle;
    private CharSequence m_drawerTitle;
    private MenuItem m_refreshItem;
    private int m_fragmentViewsCreated;
    private InSwipeRefreshLayout m_srLayout;
}
```

I am getting this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intel.dualboot/com.example.intel.dualboot.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: minor_activities.Status cannot be cast to com.example.intel.dualboot.MainFragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: minor_activities.Status cannot be cast to com.example.intel.dualboot.MainFragment
    at com.example.intel.dualboot.MainFragment.newFragment(MainFragment.java:28)
    at com.example.intel.dualboot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/lviewdimen"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your error...

android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout cannot be cast to com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize SwipeToRefresh in XML as "android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout" But you are trying to create object of that view as "com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout". So you got an error because of wrong casting of class. Change "android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout" to "com.example.intel.dualboot.InSwipeRefreshLayout" in xml to solve your problem.